# Datatables with JSON dynamic content, lose table features

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently trying to fill dynamically a table with content retrieved from a JSON Object.

Here is the table:

```html
<table id="datatable_tabletools" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-hide="phone">ID</th>
      <th data-class="expand">Nom</th>
      <th data-hide="phone">Commentaires</th>
      <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Date</th>
      <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Attachements</th>
      <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have multiple interesting features in the table such as a search option, a filter, sort, export as PDF, etc,....those features are working properly if I'm including static content such as:

```html
<tr>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>Bevis</td>
  <td>1-955-717-0835</td>
  <td>Est Ac Inc.</td>
  <td>7424</td>
  <td>Ichtegem</td>
</tr>
```

but as soon as I retrieve data table content from My JSON object, I'm not able to use those features anymore, sort doesn't work, search neither.

Here is the JavaScript I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('getAllDocuments', function(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson != null) {
      var table1 = $("#table");
      $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
        var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['id']);
        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['nom']);
        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['commentaire']);
        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['date']);
        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['id']);
        rowNew.children().eq(5).html("<a href=\"displayDocument?id=" + value['id'] + "\">Voir</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"deleteDocumentFromId?id=" + value['id'] + "\">Supprimer</a>");
        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

My table is filled correctly, but not all the functions associated. any idea on how I can fill my table with JSON content in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `ajax` option of DataTables like:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: 'data.json'
});
```

P.S. [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax) is the documentation